# Issue with WPF screen

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm new to DevExpress.
I'm using NavBarControl("Deep Blue" theme) in my WPF app for showing various menus on the main screen.Each of the menus can be collapsed and expanded.

The issue is that on trying to collapse any menu, I see a lot of flickr across the whole Navbar. I don't see this issue on expanding the menu.
Also, I see this issue only on laptop(14"" for e.g.) but not on bigger monitors.

Could you please advise?

Comment: Do you have another 14" (or smaller) Monitor to test it on? Just to exclude the possibility, that it only happens on your mashine